# Where is the Data stored on Website

Tags: html, ajax, python-2.7, xmlhttprequest, lxml

I am at this website -

```
http://www.zoominfo.com/s/#!search/company/1.64.eyJjb21wYW55TmFtZSI6xIB2YWx1xIw6ImEiLCJpc1VzZWTEjXRyxJN9fQ%3D%3D
```

If you see the company name - `Agilent Technologies Inc.`

Its `neither there in page source, nor in any json format.`

But it does show in the Dom of Chrome Developer tool.

I have looked and analysed almost every requests that it sent, but still couldn't find where this data is saved.

By where the data is saved - I am looking to find where I can scrape that data from?
If by using python-requests and BeautifulSoup

I do see an `XMLHTTPREQUEST` made, not sure what that means, or if that is the clue to my answer.

I am still learning python, and it would be a very useful information if someone helps me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do see an XMLHTTPREQUEST made, not sure what that means, or if that is the clue to my answer.

It means that javascript embedded in the page is sending an extra HHTP request to the web server.  It is likely that the "Agilent Technologies Inc." text is being returned in the server's response to that request, and the javascript in the page is then injecting the text into the DOM in the appropriate place.

> Where is the Data stored on Website

That is a completely different question ...

(You have already noted that the data (e.g. the company name) gets injected into the page displayed by your browser.)

On the server side, the data could be stored in the web server (or its back-end systems) in a variety of ways.  Or it might not be stored at all.  There is no way of knowing ... without looking at the server-side code and configurations.

Comment: Thank you so much, it indeed is there in the response received. +1 and perfect answer :-) Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

After the HTML is loaded, `js` requests for the data through an `XMLHTTPREQUEST` which is loaded right after the request is received on your client. That's why you see the DOM element right there using element inspector.

You didn't mention what goal you want to achieve or what tool you are using. Please be specific on your question. If you do not have any idea about this kind of pattern, google out `angularjs`, see some example.

Comment: @Md.Mohsin Thank you very much. Although I didn't down-voted you!